# Check if IOS status bar activity indicator is spinning/app is querying internet

Tags: ios

I want to be able to check if the app is querying the internet. Obviously when it is the network indicator in the status bar is turning. how can I get this info programatically?

Comment: Ummm, no. That's not at all obvious. I'm not even sure how that would be useful. What if some other app is? And what app are you talking about; yours? If so, the answer is, "keep track of your requests/connections"

Comment: The premace: I'm using parse. I'm doing lots of database altering and saving. If the user logs out while these queries are in progress, PFUser currentUser becomes nil so the app crashes. My way of handling this is to the let the last query finish and then change a boolean which allows the app to log out. But that is annoying to do because EVERY parse query has to alter that boolean, and one tiny mistake and the app crashes. So I was wondering if there's an easier way.

Comment: Did you check isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible? ex: [UIApplication sharedApplication]. isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible

Comment: @David Bemerguy, I just tried out those classes and managed to crash the app. I am not 100% confident they work.

Comment: I tested and it worked for me, which sdk r u using?

Comment: Xcode 5.1.1 Is that what you mean by SDK? I think the logout must be slipping between queries or something, or perhaps there's a delay before logging out. In either case, I've made a more robust version with a queue that is executed when entire methods involving multiple queries are finished.